# Help with homomorphism

Tags: group-theory

Can someone please explain where the equation on the RHS of ⇒ came from in the first line of the maths solution?

Question:

A group G is called simple if it is not the trivial group and its only normal subgroups are {e} and G. Prove that if G is simple and ϕ : G → H is a homomorphism, then either ϕ is the trivial homomorphism or ϕ is injective

Solution:

G is simple and ϕ is a homomorphism. Thus ker(ϕ) is a normal subgroup of G, so (since G is simple) either
ker(ϕ) = G, in which case ϕ is the trivial homomorphism, or ker(ϕ) = {e}, in which case ϕ is injective, since for x, y ∈ G:

ϕ(x)  =  ϕ(y) ⇒ ϕ(xy<sup>-1</sup>) = e<sub>H</sub>

⇒ xy<sup>-1</sup> ∈ ker(ϕ)

⇒ xy<sup>-1</sup> = e<sub>G</sub>

⇒ x = y

Answer (score 1):

$\phi(x) = \phi(y) \Longrightarrow$ (multiplying by $\phi(y)^{-1}$)

$\phi(x)\phi(y)^{-1} = e \Longrightarrow$ (using the homomorphism property of $\phi$)

$\phi(xy^{-1}) = e$

Answer (score 0):

A homomorphism $f$ of groups $(G,*)$ and $(H,\cdot)$ is by definition a map between the underlying sets of the groups which in addition verfies $$f(g_1*g_2) = f(g_1)\cdot f(g_2).$$

It can be proved from the definition that $f(e_G)=e_H$ and $f(g^{-1})=(f(g))^{-1}.$

So for your question, if $\phi(x)=\phi(y)$ then, multiplying by $\phi(y)^{-1}$ you get $$e_H=\phi(e_G)=\phi(yy^{-1})=\phi(y)\phi(y)^{-1}=\phi(x)\phi(y)^{-1}=\phi(x)\phi(y^{-1})=\phi(xy^{-1}).$$ Hence, $xy^{-1} \in \operatorname{ker}(\phi) = \{e_G \}.$ So $xy^{-1}=e_G$ and now you conclude that $x=y$ multiplying by $y.$